# ignore "SQL71501: unresolved reference to an object" errors

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I have a **database link** that I want to variablize in my SSDT project, but when I do it I get the following error :

> SQL71501: unresolved reference to object [$(externalServer)]

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myView]
AS
        SELECT  * FROM 
    OPENQUERY([$(externalServer)], '
        SELECT * FROM [externalDB].[schema].[table]
    ')
```

How can I ignore or get a workaround these types of errors when a database link is involved? Taking into account that I can't make a dacpac of the concerned database.

Comment: create DACPAC manually and add the only objects, you need to resolve all reference errors. In your example it would be table named [schema].[table] with any set of columns

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Thanks but creating the DACPAC manually is not a feasible for me since I would have to create thousands of tables in the concerned dacpac.

Comment: are there a lot of different objects from [$(External)] server used in your code?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Yes a lot. And the concerned database is an Oracle one so I think it is not even possible to generate a DACPAC for it.

Comment: what did you end up doing? Was this ever resolved?